# Find missing value from 2D array in php and insert missing element

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the following php array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [time] => 08:55:23 [Date] => 26 ) [1] => Array ( [time] => 09:12:57 [Date] => 28 ) [2] => Array ( [time] => 08:38:52 [Date] => 30 ) [3] => Array ( [time] => 08:55:10 [Date] => 31 ) )
```

The Dates 27, 29 are missing from the source. Would like to get a result as below:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [time] => 08:55:23 [Date] => 26 ) [1] => Array ( [time] => X [Date] => 27 ) [2] => Array ( [time] => 09:12:57 [Date] => 28 ) [3] => Array ( [time] => X [Date] => 29 ) [4] => Array ( [time] => 08:38:52 [Date] => 30 ) [5] => Array ( [time] => 08:55:10 [Date] => 31 ) )
```

Insertion of Array ( [time] => X [Date] => 27 ) and Array ( [time] => X [Date] => 28 )

Can you help me achieve it using php code please?

This is the code I have used.

```
for ( $n=26; $n<=31; $n++ ) {   
 if($pInprev[$n-26]['Date'] != $n){
   $tempadd = array(array($time=>"X","Date"=>$n));
   array_splice( $pInprev, $n-26, 0, $tempadd ); 
 }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, show us your best attempt (code). What does not work as expected, where are you stuck? Read [ask].

Comment: Solved it by using find id ==> function searchForId($id, $array) {
        $key = null;
        $val = null;
        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            if ($val['Date'] === $id) {
                return $key;
            }
        }
        return 99;
    }

Answer (score 0):

if you want to insert those tow elements use these tow functions :
`$your_array[] = Array ( [time] => X [Date] => 27 ) ; $your_array[] = and Array ( [time] => X [Date] => 28 );`

then sort values by date :

`usort(&$your_array, function($a, $b) { return $a['date'] <=> $b['date']; });`

`print_r($your_array);`

Comment: This may be used once the missing items are found. How to find the missing dates is my primary question